# Measure running time of code in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Is it possible to measure code runtime in Google Earth Engine?

To take an example from the guides, suppose we wanted to compare the performance of two functions like so:

```
var function1 = function(){
  var smallerHog = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1')
  .toArray()
  .arrayReduce(ee.Reducer.mean(), [0])
  .arrayProject([1])
  .arrayFlatten([['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'QA']])
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: 'mean',
    geometry: ee.Geometry.Point([-122.27, 37.87]).buffer(1000),
    scale: 1,
    bestEffort: true,
    tileScale: 16
  });

  print('function1', smallerHog);
}

var function2 = function(){
  var okMemory = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1')
    .mean()
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: 'mean',
      geometry: ee.Geometry.Point([-122.27, 37.87]).buffer(1000),
      scale: 1,
      bestEffort: true,
    });
  
  print('function2', okMemory);
}

function1()
function2()
```

Obviously the wheel spins a lot longer for function 1, but suppose I wanted to quantify that. How can I find out the code running time for these two functions?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fcaseyengstrom%2Freprex%3AcompareRuntime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running with the Profiler will give you some amount of comparability.

[image]